# escribir leer objeto parametrizado fichero texto

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa un poco más avanzado sobre una agencia de alquiler de vehículos.
Lo tengo estructurado de la siguiente manera:
Clase Listado. Clase común para todos los listados.
Clase Agencia donde creo los diferentes listados (clientes, vehículos, etc.) y que me servirá como base para obtener datos de los mismos.
Clase GestorAgencia. Donde tengo un menú que me deriva a los diferentes gestores (administración, alquiler y mantenimiento). Estos gestores, que reciben un parámetro de Agencia en el constructor, a su vez me derivan a otros gestores, como por ejemplo el GestorClientes, GestorVehiculos, etc. , estos solo en el GestorAdministración.
El problema lo tengo al querer guardar los datos en un fichero .txt partiendo de la clase común Listado, o sea, al escribir mediante oos.writeObject(agencia.getListado()); y leer mediante agencia.getListado()=(Listado)ois.readObject();. Siempre he hecho clases de listados independientes para cada asunto. EN este caso estoy haciendo uso de la clase Listado (genérica y común).
Aquí pongo unas clases de prueba, en las cuales se puede ver que la OPCIÓN 1, OPCIÓN 2 Y OPCIÓN 3, que ya he probado (no en esta prueba), me funcionan, pero me falla la OPCIÓN 4 que es la que pretendo poner y no me permite. Quizás lo que quiero no se pueda hacer deba yo cambiar la estructura de mi programa.
A ver si alguien me puede informar un poco.

```
public class Cliente implements Serializable{ 
private String id;//se generará solo
private String dni;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private String telefono;
private boolean licenciaConductor;
private LocalDate fechaRegistro;//se generará sola

public Cliente(String id, String dni, String nombre, String apellidos, String telefono, 
        boolean licenciaConductor, LocalDate fechaRegistro) {
    this.id=id;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.licenciaConductor = licenciaConductor;
    this.fechaRegistro=fechaRegistro;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Cliente{" + "id=" + id + ", dni=" + dni + ", nombre=" + nombre +
            ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", telefono=" + telefono +
            ", licenciaConductor=" + licenciaConductor +
            ", fechaRegistro=" + fechaRegistro + '}';
}
```

}

```
public class Listado<E> implements Serializable{
private List<E> listado;

public Listado(){
    listado=new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<E> getListado(){
    return listado;
}

public int size(){
    return listado.size();
}

public void add(E e){
    listado.add(e);
}

public void listar(){
    System.out.println("ok");
    for(E e:listado){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Agencia {
private Listado<Cliente> listadoClientes;

public Agencia(){
    listadoClientes=new Listado();
}

public Listado<Cliente> getListado(){
    return listadoClientes;
}
```

}

```
public class GestorClientes {
private Scanner sc;
private int opcion;
private Cliente cliente;

private Agencia agencia;

private File fileClientes;
private ObjectOutputStream oos;
private ObjectInputStream ois;

public GestorClientes() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    opcion=0;
    agencia=new Agencia();
    fileClientes=new File("/ficheros/vehiculos_alquiler/clientes.txt");       
}

public void writeFile(File file){ 
    try{ 
        oos=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileClientes));
        //OPCIONES 1,2,3: oos.writeObject(clientes);
        oos.writeObject(agencia.getListado());
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado.");
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            if(oos!=null){
                oos.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void readFile(File file){
    try{            
        ois=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileClientes));
        
        //OPCIÓN 1: clientes=(ListadoClientes)ois.readObject();
        //OPCION 2: clientes=(ListadoClientes2)ois.readObject();
        //OPCIÓN 3: clientes=(ListadoClientes3<Cliente>)ois.readObject();
        //OPCIÓN 4:
        agencia.getListado()=(Listado<Cliente>)ois.readObject();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado.");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        System.out.println(cnfe.getMessage());
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            if(ois!=null){
                ois.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());         
        }
    }
}

public void menu(){
    System.out.print("MENU\n1. Crear cliente\n2. Listar clientes\n0.- Salir\n"
            + "Elegir una de las anteriores opciones: ");
}

public void gestion(){
    //readFile(fileClientes);
    do{
        try{
            menu();
            opcion=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            switch(opcion){
                case 1:
                    create();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //clientes.listar();
                    agencia.getListado().listar();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("SALIR");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("ERROR. Fuera de rango [0-4].");
                    break;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("ERROR. No es un entero.");
        }  
    }while(opcion!=0);
    writeFile(fileClientes);
}

public void create(){
    System.out.println("NUEVO CLIENTE");
    System.out.print("Intro id: ");
    String id=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Intro dni: ");
    String dni=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Intro nombre: ");
    String nombre=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Intro apellidos: ");
    String apellidos=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Intro telefono: ");
    String telefono=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Tiene licencia conductor (true|false): ");
    boolean licencia=Boolean.parseBoolean(sc.nextLine());
    LocalDate fechaRegistro=LocalDate.now();
    cliente=new Cliente(id,dni,nombre,apellidos,telefono,licencia,fechaRegistro);
    //OPCIÓN 1 Y 3: clientes.add(cliente);
    //OPCION 2: clientes.insertarPrincipio(cliente);
    agencia.getListado().add(cliente);
}

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    GestorClientes gc=new GestorClientes();
    gc.gestion();
}
```

}

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hay mucho texto, mucho codigo, pero no queda claro cual es tu problema...

Comment: " El problema lo tengo al querer guardar los datos".. que problema??? te falto aclarar eso...

Comment: *"pero me falla la OPCIÓN 4"* -> Normal que te falle, no hay `case 4` en tu `switch`. Recomiendo usar el enlace [edit] para añadir más información sobre el problema, preferiblemente añadiendo también un [mre]... no necesitamos proyectos enteros, solo el código mínimo necesario para reproducir tu problema con un ejemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, sobre el programa, he puesto los listados en el Gestor Agencia, donde también he puesto el menu.Y entonces, con pequeñas variaciones, me ha admitido bien los métodos writeFile() y readFile() sobre un listado parametrizado. La prueba es apenas muy poco diferente al programa.
Gracias.